# Can't run FlightGear from PlayDeb on Ubuntu 12.04 32bits

Tags: games, software-sources

Trying to run FlightGear 2.6 from PlayDeb on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bits, I get this error every time :

> fgfs: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libsgtsync.so.2.6.0: undefined symbol: svn_subr_version

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem :

- I removed the PlayDeb repository :
  `sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games"`.
- Then, I updated the sources :
  `sudo apt-get update`.
- Then I removed all fgfs files :
  `sudo apt-get remove flightgear fgfs*`.
- Then I reinstalled FlightGear 2.4 :
  `sudo apt-get install flightgear`.
- Then I added the PlayDeb repository again :
  `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games"`.
- And finally, I upgraded :
  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`